# Where is the [Github] repo for `gcloud` CLI (google-cloud-sdk)?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I'm looking for the Python source code to the `gcloud` CLI (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install). This seems like a simple question but I have searched for a while and not found anything.

I am *not* referring to the Python client code.

I found the local installation using `gcloud info` which is located at `/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk` on my machine. The root Python file here is `gcloud_main.py` so it's easy to see whether or not a repo is the right one or not.

I'm thinking this may not be a public repo at all which is why I can't find it.

Comment: did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

Found this [unofficial](https://github.com/twistedpair/google-cloud-sdk) repo sometime ago